# Extended Liouville’s theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that the Extended Liouville’s theorem states that:

> An entire function $f(x)$ with $|f(z)|<C|z|^n$, for natural number $n$, is a polynomial of degree at most $n$.

I am wondering whether there is another function, except polynomial, satisfies the condition of the theorem.

That is, can I find holomorphic functions, not polynomials, with the property  $|f(z)|<C|z|^n$?

Comment: So there's this well-known theorem, and you're wondering if there are examples that show the theorem is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

No. actually, that's exactly what the theorem is saying. Any entire (i.e. holomorphic on all of $\mathbb{C}$) function satisfying that inequality must be a polynomial. Furthermore, we can place an upper bound on the degree of the polynomial.

Pretty surprising, huh?

Comment: Perhaps he is asking if there is a holomorphic function defined on a smaller set than the entire plane?